# Adding products in django-oscar homepage

Tags: django, django-oscar

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display products inside my homepage. I'm building my website using the sandbox that already comes with django-oscar (I cloned the project from Github).

I discovered that the default homepage is controlled by 'promotions' app. However, my products are just being displayed inside 'http://localhost:8000/catalogue' (controlled by 'catalogue' app).

Is there a way to display the products in my homepage? Or will I have to change the default app that controls the homepage? (in this case, how can I do that?)

EDIT 1: I believe that I found a solution. You can follow the tutorial [How to Customize an Existing View](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_customise_a_view.html); however, you need to make some changes, so your code must looks like this:

```
 from oscar.apps.catalogue.views import CatalogueView

 class HomeView(CatalogueView):
     template_name = 'promotions/home.html'
```

This way you will have access to the products in your 'promotions/home.html'. I'm not sure if it is the best way to implement this, if someone else has an alternative to this solution, please comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this purpose Oscar has an app called [`promotions`](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/ref/apps/promotions.html). This application is responsible for rendering blocks of content on the homepage, among other things (as I can see you found out from the documentation).

Usually you would use the promotion app to add products and other types of content to a page. This can be done from the Dashboard, using `Content blocks`, which can be found under the `Content` menu.

There are a few types of promotions that you can define (single product, automatic, and hand picked product list, and others).

After defining your promotion, you will be able to associate it with a page route, which in your case should be `/`.

If you choose to change this behaviour, then the [documentation](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/index.html#customisation) should provide a good starting point.

**Update 2021.02.12:**

Django Oscar Promotions is an app for Dashboard-editable promotional content in Oscar. It was formerly a part of Oscar core, but has now been separated into a standalone app.

See here: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-promotions

Comment: I've tried to add a block content to a page; however, there is an error ocurring "The URL "/" does not exist", seems that I can't insert a block content into my root URL. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: What version of Oscar are you using, and can you show me how you're adding its url's to your projects `urls.py`? (just the line concerning oscar)

Comment: Actually I imported the project from Github, so I'm not using an official release. I'm adding the Oscar's urls using `url(r'', include(application.urls)),`. I imported the project from Github because after I install Oscar in an virtualenv environment, I wasn't able to find its folder (that I'd like to have access to make some changes in its files).

Comment: Everything looks fine, have you tried leaving the input box empty? (although I'm quite sure the same error will pop up) You should probably go through Oscar's documentation a little bit, one of the nicer features it has is the ability to let you swap out any of it's pieces for your own. I wouldn't recommend forking it unless you're actually doing some very heavy changes, and you don't mind giving up on future updates.

Comment: I installed it again and I discovered where the original folder is. My question now is how can I display the products using a customized template? Will I have to import some tag or to alter something in the view?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to modify the default templates for the different promotions content types. You can achieve this by overriding the templates provided by Oscar (found here - https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/tree/master/src/oscar/templates/oscar/promotions). This is described here - http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_customise_templates.html, I recommend that you consider overriding the default templates (second method).

Comment: Yes, I was overriding the default templates; however, I was trying to figure out how could I import the products to the new templates. I realized that I need to load the promotions_tags and also loop through the promotions, something like that: {% for promotion in promotions_page %} {% render_promotion promotion %}{% endfor %}, I still don't know all the variables that I have access in my templates, do you know if there is any documentation for this?

Comment: As far as I know, the documentation doesn't go that far. You will have to make do by taking the default templates as examples, and by navigating through the source of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to watching catalogue as a default page and I had find solution through nginx **rewrite** func at the end of */etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject*

This file looks like this:

```
server {
server_name yourdomainorip.com;

access_log off;

location /static/ {
    alias /opt/myenv/static/;
}
location /media/ {
    alias /opt/myenv/media/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
    rewrite ^(/)$ http://yourdomainorip.com/catalogue/$2 permanent;
}
```