# Display random django oscar products on landing page

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-oscar

Currently my Django Oscar landing page only displays the open menu of product categories. I want to display random products on the landing page, similar to that described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013814/adding-products-in-django-oscar-homepage) post, but I don't think promotions are the way to do it. How can I display the products on this page, without using the `promotions` app? Edit the template?

Tried to associate a promotion with `/`, but it failed, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `content blocks` from the dashboard. I created a `content-block` with a url of `/`. Initially, this was causing an error, but after some searching, [THIS](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/1815) post pointed me in the right direction. I had to edit the base oscar `apps/dashboard/promotions/forms.py` file in my virtual environment, and add

```
page_url
```

to the `class Meta` `fields` attribute

```
class Meta:
model = PagePromotion
fields = ['position', 'page_url']
```

I was then able to successfully add promotions to the landing page.

Comment: Can you put here a gist with your solution?

Comment: I believe the change is now included in master repository for Django-oscar